# Power BI - Create table from Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

In Power BI I have a list of inventory transactions (InventTrans) with date, quantity and value for movements in and out of the inventory.

There are 1 million lines of inventory transactions, and the sum of all lines for each ItemID gives the inventory value of that item.

I have created a measure to calculate number of days from last movement until today:

Days since last movement = DATEDIFF(CALCULATE(MAX(InventTrans[Date]),TODAY(),DAY)

and a measure (InventoryStatus) to group each ItemID based on this result.

I have used
InventoryStatus = IF([Days since last movement]<183, "Movement last six months", ("Six months to a year", "Over 1 year". and so on)

Now I want to create a table with ItemID and the measure InventoryStatus.
My aim is to use InventoryStatus as a filter, so maybe there is better way to achieve this without creating a new table with ItemID and InventoryStatus.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming inventory status is a property of the item, not the transaction, your proposed approach is probably correct. The data model will be more intuitive and more efficient if you create an `items` table that has `ItemID`, `InventoryStatus`, and any other item-level data. After linking the two tables together `InventoryStatus` can be used as a filter for transactions.